# Foreach Line Numbers

Tags: php

I want to give numbers to each **foreach** line.

Please see below code, where instead of **LINE NUMBER** I want to be 0 for first line, 1 for second, 2 for third and so on.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $action; ?>" target="_blank">

foreach ($items as $item ) {
$itemname = $item['name'];

<input type="hidden" name="item[**LINE NUMBER**][name]" value="<?php echo $itemname; ?>" />

}

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Could you tell me how I can achieve this?

Comment: hey! Have you looked my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($items as $item ) {
$itemname = $item['name'];

<input type="hidden" name="item[$i][name]" value="<?php echo $itemname; ?>" />
$i++;
}
```

Comment: It could be simpler to use: `foreach ($items as $i=>$item )`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to start with `0` you can just leave it empty `item[][name]`:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $action; ?>" target="_blank">
<?php foreach ($items as $item ) { ?>
<input type="hidden" name="item[][name]" value="<?=$item['name']?>" />
<?php }?>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

On submit PHP will index your array automatically:

```
echo $_POST['item'][0]['name'];
echo $_POST['item'][1]['name'];
//etc..
```